# nginx error --> expecting "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1

Tags: linux, nginx, server, config

I'm getting mad as I cant find the error in this code for the default config file for nginx. I have a server where I'm trying to configure the certificates to access it with https. I've got everything in the sites-enables/default file config. Don't need other files for the momment. This is what I've got so far in the config file in `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name shiny-server.modlearth.com;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.modlearth.com;
    }

    location /shiny/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3838/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        rewrite ^(/shiny/[^/]+)$ $1/ permanent;
    }

    location /rstudio/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8787/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/shiny-server.modlearth.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/shiny-server.modlearth.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/shiny-server.modlearth.com/chain.pem;
}
```

This is the error:

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details.
$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I think that the brackets are well placed. What do am I missing?

Comment: Is your file alright, where this one gets imported - normally the `nginx.conf`?

Comment: I think you should just debug this a bit. Move it somewhere else and start nginx without that file - have a look whats happening. Else just comment all lines out and start with just the map block and have a look whats happening. Think that way you will find the issue. Copied it to my instance and modified it so I can run it - worked without issues.

Comment: I'll go with this, commenting parts until I get the issue

Comment: Use `sudo nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files.